# show data in TextArea java

Tags: java, textarea

I'm trying to show all data that I got in the textarea

```
    public static void randNumQueue(){
    Queue<String> myQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    if(average12==30){
        long range = (long)randNum2 - (long)randNum1 + 1;
        long fraction = (long)(range * random.nextDouble());
        number = (int)(fraction + randNum1);
        System.out.println(number);
        Set mySet = new HashSet();
        for (int j = 0; j<number; j++)
        {
            int pick;
            do{
                pick = random.nextInt(number)+1;
            }while(!mySet.add(pick));
            myQueue.add(Integer.toString(pick));
        }
        System.out.println("the queue size: "+myQueue.size());
        sizeQ = myQueue.size();
        Iterator it = myQueue.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
                String iteratorValue = (String)it.next();
                Qnum = Integer.parseInt(iteratorValue);
                System.out.println("queue next value: "+Qnum);
            }
    }
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(b1)){
        randomAverage();
        testAmount = testAmount + 1;
        label5.setText(""+testAmount);
        area3.setText(""+sizeQ);
        area1.setText(""+Qnum);
    }

}
```

area1 is area text which I'm trying to show all data which I got from IteratorValue

from the above function area1 just showed the last value which I got from iteratorValue

anyone know how to show all the value in area1(textarea)?

Comment: 1) Is this buttons based in Swing, AWT, ..something else? 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setText` when you want to replace the contents of the text area, use [`JTextArea#append`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) when you want to add text to the end of the text area

**Updated**

It's a "little" difficult to assess what it is you are trying to do, but something like...

```
while(it.hasNext()){
    String iteratorValue = (String)it.next();
    area1.append(iteratorValue + "\n");
    Qnum = Integer.parseInt(iteratorValue);
    System.out.println("queue next value: "+Qnum);
}
```

In your action performed method, remove `area1.setText(""+Qnum);`.  This will append each result to the text area.  If you want to clear the text, use something like `area1.setText(null)`